# Type narrowing of a discriminated union via mapping instead of switch

Tags: typescript, discriminated-union

My goal is to use an object to render a React component based on a data type property. I'm trying to find a way to avoid `switch` cases when I need to narrow a discriminated union type in TypeScript. The regular approach is to write an if-else or a switch and TS narrows the value automatically:

```js
type AView = {type: 'A', name: string} 
type BView = {type: 'B', count: number} 
type View = AView | BView

const prints =  {
    'A': (view: AView) => `this is A: ${view.name}`,
    'B': (view: BView) => `this is B. Count: ${view.count}`,
} as const

const outputWorks = (view: View): string => {
  switch (view.type) {
    case 'A':
    // or prints['A'](view)
      return prints[view.type](view)
    case 'B':
    // or prints['B'](view)
      return prints[view.type](view)
  }
}

outputWorks({type: 'A', name: 'John'})
```

I'm wondering whether it is possible to avoid the switch and convince TS that the object can narrow the data:

```js
type AView = {type: 'A', name: string} 
type BView = {type: 'B', count: number} 
type View = AView | BView

const prints =  {
    'A': (view: AView) => `this is A: ${view.name}`,
    'B': (view: BView) => `this is B. Count: ${view.count}`,
} as const

const outputFail = (view: View): string => prints[view.type](view)

outputFail({type: 'A', name: 'John'})
```

With this approach I get the error `The intersection 'AView & BView' was reduced to 'never' because property 'type' has conflicting types in some constituents.` because the TS does not narrow the type.

You can see this code in the [TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=38&ssc=34&pln=38&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKu0F4oHICCyoB8UCFkChRIpUA1ASwgHcokBvIiALhXQBooA7AQwFtmoAZ2AAncpwDmAXyiF4UHBWq0oDeC2R4OAYwD2AV07AWnfbwBGEETLnElNJGUo1si5-nx7OwqGDFHUFQAKADdnFidlAEpaAD5VfCgkqBEIYH0RTigAA2AAC3JBKEKSFgASOjDqADoefils-CkPLx8-cWAcYKqqFjdouITklLSMrNyCopKcaqgAYQMjcsrnar1DYAamlt1vYF9-YCKkIeS0ZBZ2gLZEs7xLw5wbmW4i1uAdvagDYDB9YAA6roRABrY5QULhKD2KIsYT+CSDOi3QRUcjAbR5CE9aqMGLI4baV7Qc5MW5JAD0FO+IgOHUEAG1zgBdSHUKLk5KpdKZOlGRk4xisnocwnE3AXTlUml8o5MvDC5yi4YjHlZK5ywXwRXs27NZoefDSwAy5FAACa6CCCTjIfZUYEgzy7Hw-P77JBs3rQpVw0TiREIeIEqDvKAAMyySA1AtWQtu3LG4c4no5Btd-yCakgGnYXD4AmQACldHkbVIokA) and play with it.

I'm investigating this issue for a week already and I'm about to give up. I've seen several similar threads, but couldn't make this code work.

Comment: This is the issue described in [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581) and the recommended approach is described in [ms/TS#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109). If I follow that approach with your example I get the version in [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WvqeAm) which works.  Does that fully address your question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz it works until I want to use the variable as a React component. I've tried several approaches, but I have the error: "Type '{ view: View<K>; }' is not assignable to type 'LibraryManagedAttributes<{ A: ({ view }: { view: { type: "A"; } & { name: string; }; }) => Element; B: ({ view }: { view: { type: "B"; } & { count: number; }; }) => Element; }[K], { view: View<K>; }>'"


I've assembled an example in Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/summer-lake-2rximm?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: I'm afraid I have no idea, since that `LibraryManagedAttributes` is some kind of TS-internal thing for dealing with JSX.  If you use regular function call style like [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WP1Lew) shows, it works.  At this point I could suggest you either let me write up the current thing and you accept it, or you [edit] the question saying this has to work with JSX syntax and you should provide a [mre] of the relevant call in the text of the question.  How should we proceed here?

Comment: @jcalz you answer is good, feel free to add it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The underlying issue is the lack of direct support for *correlated unions* as described in [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  Inside `outputFail`, the type of `prints[view.type]` is the [union type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) `((view: AView) => string) | ((view: BView) => string)`, and the type of `view` is the union type `AView | BView`.  If all you knew is that you had a function `f` of the same type as `prints[view.type]`, and a value `v` of the same type as `view`, then it wouldn't be safe to call `f(v)`, because what if `v` is an `AView` but `f` is a `(view: BView) => string`?  Given the types involved, this looks like a possibility, and the compiler complains.

Of course it's not *really* a possibility.  The union type of `prints[view.type]` and the union type of `view` are *correlated* in such a way that they are always appropriate for each other.  But the compiler has no way to represent such correlated unions.

---

The suggested way to approach these things is described in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109).  The idea is to replace unions with [generics](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), and refactor your types in such a way as to make it obvious to the compiler that the function and the argument are compatible. That is, `f` would be of some generic type `(arg: Arg<K>) => void`, and `v` would be of generic type `Arg<K>`.

Here's one implementation:

```
interface BaseView {
  A: { name: string };
  B: { count: number };
}

type View<K extends keyof BaseView = keyof BaseView> = {
  [P in K]: { type: P } & BaseView[P]
}[K];
```

Here we've redefined `View` to be a generic *distributive object type* built from a "base" mapping.  The type `View` with no type argument is equivalent to your original version, while you can recover your `AView` and `BView` types by specifying the right key:

```
type AView = View<"A">;
type BView = View<"B">;


const printA = (view: AView) => {
  return `this is A: ${view.name}`
}

const printB = (view: BView) => {
  return `this is B. Count: ${view.count}`
}
```

Now, when we declare `prints`, we need to write its type explicitly in terms of a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) over the same "base" mapping, so that later when we index into it, we get a generic type instead of a union:

```
const prints: { [K in keyof BaseView]: (view: View<K>) => string } = {
  'A': printA,
  'B': printB,
}
```

And here we go:

```
const output = <K extends keyof BaseView>(view: View<K>): string => {
  const fn = prints[view.type];
  return fn(view); // okay
}
```

If you look, `fn` is of a type equivalent to `(view: View<K>) => string`, and `view` is of type `View<K>`, so everything works.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEJwM4QGrAgd2QG8AoZZAQQC5jkQ4BbCGjMKUAc2QF8BuMtDSLIEAewCu4GiHEMARtB79uJMAE8ADilwEAPAGlkEAB6QQAEwzIA1hDWiYaTDjyEAvDbsOnWHfgB8yB6k5ADaAArIoMj6ALpCyOpaNJHcyABkPi4EEbEk3KFx-KqaKBR+Qch+ugBEFDX+-EkoqBUe1TWoDcUkYiCsyBrs4BSVABQAbq405a4AlEGBIchQEGDiUCDIAAZgABbAVoeUNAAkRFMEAHT0TNzb+SS9ov1gg8NgqOOX+DSt84tiAJVutNjt9sdjqgrsgAMISKTIc4-K5iSRge6PZ6vd6gMAYBKFKJbWz2RzoXyueLISbTKquAz+BZuQKsYZcNLBAQAcgo3JoQzxFAANDzUPzceBUKKVE9sQMJGANOI3h4DEZTBALFZSd4KdkArSCDRqvomSw2JxAcs+gMYFsPILwBhQijmnlyCCNlt7Ub8HMsYrlWAxsJmjRedzhXRGMxkNyAFKiPYgbk8OZAA)